# How to delete an account without providing personal information?

Tags: facebook, account-management

I have a never used a Facebook account, which regularly spams the address it is registered on with "maybe that's your friend?" E-Mails and fake contact requests, I would like to delete. Furthermore I do not want Facebook to have the data anymore.

I know the password but, when logging in, Facebook requires a governmental id document or at least some invoice with my name on it. 
I want to delete my account and do **not** want provide even more personal information to them.

**How can I get Facebook to permanently delete all my data without providing additional data about me?**

I could possibly at least convince them to stop sending mail to the address, but I guess in the best case they disable the Facebook account, but do not delete the associated data.

Answer (score 2):

Basically they are suspecting that this is a fake account as you don't use this account regularly, and that's why they are asking for government id proof to confirm that this account belongs to you. And without login to your account you will not be able delete the account.

I don't think you would be able to delete your account without providing addition data, as you are not able to login.

It would be better if you can provide the id proof, then login to your account and change the related setting of not using your id proof and they will delete your id proof within 30 days, as [Facebook claim](https://www.facebook.com/help/155050237914643?helpref=faq_content):

> If you don't want Facebook to use your ID to improve our automated systems for detecting fake IDs, you can adjust your **Identity Confirmation Settings**. If you turn this option off, the copy of your ID will be deleted within 30 days of submission or when you turned this option off.

Once you have access to your account, you can [delete your account permanently](https://www.facebook.com/help/224562897555674):

> To permanently delete your account:

1. Click *down arrow* at the top right of any Facebook page.
2. Click **Settings**.
3. Click **Your Facebook Information** in the left column.
4. Click **Delete Your Account and Information**, then click **Delete My Account**.
5. Enter your password, click **Continue** and then click **Delete Account**.

Once you delete the account permanently, all your data will be deleted from the site.

Comment: I have two issues there: a) I do not know the birthdate in the account. I never wanted to provide them too much information and made something up, but I am not sure what it was, so it will not match the ID documents. When this was a security question, I tried several possible dates and were wrong and b) I do not really trust them, so I would like not to given them even more valuable information like ID documents. I do not really understand, why they need to identify me to delete an account associated to my e-mail, when they think it may be fake anyway.

Comment: @allo: I understand your concern. You are right at your place. But here we cannot do anything. They are not going delete your profile until you tell them to do so. And to tell them about this you have to login. And to login you need to verify yourself. There is no other way in my knowledge. Now days, they are following their policy very strictly. So if they want ID documents to let you login, you have to provide. Do not worry about birth date, if you want give ID doc. You can give.

Comment: I will see. Maybe somebody else did it in a privacy friendly way and has another answer, maybe I just let the account be, or I comply with their procedure. I consider what I can do with GDPR, but I think for a GDPR request I need some ID document as well. But it may have a better protection to be completely deleted afterwards.